# truffle migrate specific file

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

Is it possible to `truffle migrate` only one specific file?

I found this on the internet: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-migrate/issues/23

but `truffle migrate -from 2` starts to migrate from file 2_... and goes then to the next.
My goal is to migrate only file 2_...

Comment: In the issue you're linking, people are also mentioning a ``--to`` parameter. Did you try ``-f 2 --to 2``? It worked for me.

Comment: @ivicaa Sorry my bad, I miss read this. Thanks a lot for your help - its working :)
Just another question: when I run truffle migrate for file 3_... and this deploy fails - how can I retry only this deploy 3_... again? Because it says "network is up to date" but the transaction failed and isnt even visible on rinkeby network. When I use --reset it starts to deploy again all files.

Comment: Did you try to add the --reset prameter?

Comment: yes, with --reset its working but he is going to deploy then all files again and my goal is to redeploy only one file after its somehow failed.
I just had this situation on rinkeby: I ran truffle migrate 3_... it contains 2 SC, one he deployed fine the second one ran into a problem (I think it was a problem of rinkeby network). I saw on my geth node that it received the deploy transaction but it didnt arrive to rinkeby network

Comment: the console log of this situation: https://pastebin.com/DB6whBTH

and when I retried to deploy it again it said network is up to date. But obviously it ran into a problem. The only help in this situation was --reset and rename all other migration files to x_... so he did deploy only 3_...
I am just not sure if this was the best solution :p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the flag `--f` for the first migration and `--to` for the last migration like this:

```bash
truffle migrate --f 2 --to 2
```

Source: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-migrate/issues/23#issuecomment-401290273

The "from" parameter can be written in two forms:

- -from N
- --f N

Comment: for some reasons it gives me "> Warning: possible unsupported (undocumented in help) command line option: --from" and keep running from the first script

Comment: You can use "-from", with 1 hypens, or "--f", with 2 hypens. "--from" does not exists.